# Pandas: загрузка данных. Первые шаги

Tags: python, pandas

Есть ли какое то руководство, методология или книга, где можно найти какие действия необходимо предпринимать при первоначальной обработки загруженных данных? Например, чтобы типы данных были выставлены правильно или как эти типы данных выставлять? Возможно необходимо делать какой-то обзор данных сначала, на предмет где какие данные имеются в датафрейме, может лишние точки или еще какие то символы и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хорошо понимаете английский, то можно почитать любой **EDA** на **Kaggle** например по ***Titanic dataset***. К примеру [вот этот](https://www.kaggle.com/dejavu23/titanic-eda-to-ml-beginner), но вообще их там полно. Есть аналогичное и [на русском](https://neurohive.io/ru/osnovy-data-science/razbor-resheniya-zadachi-titanik-na-kaggle-dlya-nachinajushhih/). В любом случае посмотрите в сторону **EDA (exploratory data analysis)**, там обычно смотрят на все аспекты входных данных, включая распределение, выбросы, **NA** и прочее.

Answer (score 1):

Всегда, когда вижу такие вопросы, мне становится немного не по себе. С одной стороны я понимаю, что для ответа на такой вопрос надо просто набрать поисковый запрос в Гугл и сразу-же получить ответ, а не ждать часами, пока кто-нибудь на форуме сделает это за тебя, потом разместит тут ответ, потом его еще прочитать да понять нужно. Ну не верю я, что сегодня есть кто-то младше 10 и старше 80 лет, кто не умеет самостоятельно Гуглить. Но ведь люди так поступают. Наверное потому, что у них в стране им отключили Интернет или электричество, или потому что они плохо видят, или потому что их родители пускают к компьютеру на 20 минут в день. И им недоступны те возможности, которые доступны всем другим людям. Поэтом надо им помочь и сделать такую подборку.

- [data-cleansing-and-transformation](https://quantdare.com/data-cleansing-and-transformation/)
- [python-data-cleaning-numpy-pandas](https://realpython.com/python-data-cleaning-numpy-pandas/)
- [cleaning-and-preparing-data-in-python](http://sergilehkyi.com/ru/cleaning-and-preparing-data-in-python/)
- [3-steps-to-a-clean-dataset-with-pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-steps-to-a-clean-dataset-with-pandas-2b80ef0c81ae)
- [data-preprocessing-art-or-science](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-preprocessing-art-or-science-7d13ae5663fa)
- [the-ultimate-guide-to-data-cleaning](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-data-cleaning-3969843991d4)
- [essential-toolbox-data-cleaning](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/12/essential-toolbox-data-cleaning.html)
- [practical-guide-data-preprocessing-python-scikit-learn](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/07/practical-guide-data-preprocessing-python-scikit-learn/)
- [Methods-for-handling-missing-values-1](https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/Methods-for-handling-missing-values-1)
- [guide-data-exploration](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/guide-data-exploration/)

Надеюсь, что дал вам возможность понять что к чему. А далее - уже по ссылкам, и желаю вам, что-бы интернет стал вам, наконец, доступен не только для игр.

Comment: Спасибо, что помогаете.